# DataSource PostgreSQL Widlfly

Tags: java, jpa, wildfly, intellij, datasource

Estou tentando configurar um `DataSource`com `PostgreSQL`, mas ta lançando essa `Exception`

```
23:36:46,381 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "meuprojeto")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.meuprojeto#meuprojeto-dev" => "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"}}
23:36:46,382 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "meuprojeto.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.meuprojeto#meuprojeto-dev" => "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"}}
23:36:46,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'meuprojeto#meuprojeto-dev'
23:36:46,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment meuprojeto (runtime-name: meuprojeto.war) in 152ms
[2017-10-24 11:36:46,614] Artifact meuprojeto:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2017-10-24 11:36:46,614] Artifact meuprojeto:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.meuprojeto#meuprojeto-dev" => "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"}}
```

**DataSource** no `standalone.xml` do **Wildfly**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/meuprojetoDS" pool-name="meuprojetoDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/meuprojetodb</connection-url>
    <connection-property name="DatabaseName">
        meuprojetodb
    </connection-property>
    <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>root</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

**module.xml** do driver PostgreSQL

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.postgresql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.1.4.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
          <module name="javax.api"/>
          <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Meu **persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="meuprojeto-dev" transaction-type="JTA">

        <description>Dev Persistence Unit</description>

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/meuprojetoDS</jta-data-source>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Verifique se a lib org.dom4j está no seu classpath. Provavelmente ela está dando conflito com a lib do jboss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque o WildFly já possui as libs do hibernate no próprio servidor em versões diferentes que as do classpath da aplicação.

Ao marcar a lib como provided no Maven você define que usará a biblioteca do servidor e não a do seu classpath local Ex:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Para usar as bibliotecas que existem na sua aplicação sem o **provided** é necessário configurar as mesmas no MANIFEST.MF, Ex:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
...
Dependencies: org.hibernate
```

Vide [Documentação do Widlfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-PackagingtheHibernateJPApersistenceproviderwithyourapplication)